# LM324 leaking voltage to other pins

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have the following schematic on breadboard and I'm using output-3:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFQntF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is all inverting and non-inverting inputs of LM324 have ~1V, output-1 have 0V but output-2 and output-4 showing ~21V.

I tested three different LM324 and all of them are showing the same result, I asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/459608/185519) earlier and the answers was opamp outputs are isolated, Why all other pins of LM324 outputting some voltage?

Comment: is it a problem?

Comment: @Jasen How am I supposed to use other opamps of LM324, for example for low-side current sensing when it's outputting voltage?

Comment: did you try connecting it?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, two gain resistors of inverting input was getting hot while they were just connected to ground and output!

Comment: Show us the full circuit including the problematic current sensing part, and report all the voltages.

Comment: that seems unusual, the LM324 output is lowe powered and the input extremely low powered.

Comment: Please after down-voting tell me what was the reason so I can improve the question...

Comment: you drew a circuit that seems to have little bearing on the question. but not my vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's in the data sheet that the LM324 input pins are current-sources.
"input bias current"  page 5 of the datasheet

This is normal, and the current is small (less than half a microamp, usually much less) once you hook it up to something the voltage caused by the small current will dissappear as the current is absorbed by the signal source.

the outputs will do whatever the inputs tell them to, and with the inputs unconnected the outputs will just float.

it's reccomended to configure unused op-amps in a package as followers ( connect the inverting input to the output)  the non inverting inout can be connected to any suitable voltage source, (with LM324 the negative supply would e a good choice).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ7FKt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: after applying the voltage those "unwanted" voltages disappeared as you said, Thanks and sorry for not reading the datasheet before posting the question.